# PDF-Form \textfield output with comma instead of dot (AFNumber-Format)

Tags: hyperref, javascript

I build a pdf-form with the package `hyperref`. I am using this form to calcualate two sums and the difference between this sums. Therefore I am using the package `insdljs`. Everything works fine as long as I am using number-expressions like `10.3 + 2.4 = 12.7`. But this Form is supposed to be used by Germans who type number like `10,3 + 2,4 = ???`. My document isn't able to accept this arguments. I already tried to change the output-format directly in the `\textfield`, using `AFNumber_Format` like this:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|l l l l|}
Ausgaben1: 
& 
\TextField[name=a1, bordercolor=yellow!30,color=blue, width=3.7cm, 
onblur={berechne(),format={AFNumber_Format(2,2,1,0,"",true);}}]{} 
&   
Eigenmittel1:  
& 
\TextField[name=e1, bordercolor=yellow!30,color=blue, width=3.7cm,
 onblur={berechne()}, format={AFNumber_Format(2,2,1,0,"",true);}]{}
{...} \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Then I also tried to change the format at the same environment, where I defined my calculations:

```
 \begin{insDLJS}[]{JSDateiname}{irgendeinTitel}
function initialisiereFelder() {       
  AllFields = newarray("a1","a2","a3","a4","a6","a5","e1",e2","e3","e4",
                   "Ergebnis1","Ergebnis2","Endergebnis","Zuschuss");    
    for (i=0; i<AllFields.length; i++) {
        this.getField(AllFields[i]).AFNumber_Format(2,1,2,0,"",true);
    }   
 }
 \end{insDLJS}
```

I don't understand, how I can use `AFNumber_Format` correctly. Why this command didn't work in my document? Maybe there is a easier way the solve my problem. Is it possible the change the language of the `textfields` to German. I am already using  `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`. So the whoole document is in German, but the `textfields` , where I can type comment have a English spelling verification.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.